# Does the App Store remove architectures from an IPA?

Tags: ios, app-store, filesize, ipa

Since the [announcement by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b) that all apps distributed by the App Store require 64-bit support, I've had to build multiple-architecture fat binaries that increase the size of the resulting IPA. Does this size increase directly affect my users, or **does the App Store strip out irrelevant architectures from an IPA containing fat binaries when downloading to a device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that they currently do, since [that feature was announced for iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html).

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app
>   bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the
>   executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target
>   device. You continue to develop and upload full versions of your app
>   to iTunes Connect. The App Store will create and deliver different
>   variants based on the devices your app supports.